# Python: Roman Numeral to Int, hitching on 'C' calculation

Tags: python

My code isn't printing the correct number for one of the test cases - "MCMXCVI"

It should print: 1996.
It's currently printing 2106.

I suspect it's failing on the validation of the 'C' element after checking an 'M' element in my last elif statement. However, I typed it correctly and don't know why it would be. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: So I still can't figure it out. I know it's failing on "IV" and "MCM" - but why? I'm parsing everything in and it SHOULDN'T - I'm definitely missing something. I need some n00b explaining, please!

2nd Edit: Got it! I traced "IV" METICULOUSLY and super slowly by hand - I figured out just as I added the V (5), I'd minus 1 AFTERWARDS, instead of adding 5 - 1 (4). So I'd end up with 5. This logic is failing on the others as well. I'll have to first check the value of the element before, THEN add. Thanks all!

```
class Solution:
def romanToInt(self, roman):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    sum = 0
    for element in range(0, len(roman)):
        if roman[element] == 'I':
            sum += 1

        elif roman[element] == 'V':
            sum += 5
            if roman[element - 1] == 'I':
                sum -= 1

        elif roman[element] == 'X':
            sum += 10
            if roman[element - 1] == 'I':
                sum -= 1

        elif roman[element] == 'C':
            sum += 100
            if roman[element - 1] =='X':
                sum -= 10

        elif roman[element] == 'L':
            sum += 50
            if roman[element - 1] == 'X':
                sum -= 10

        elif roman[element] == 'D':
            sum += 500
            if roman[element - 1] == 'C':
                sum -= 100

        elif roman[element] == 'M':
            sum += 1000
            if roman[element - 1] == 'C':
                sum -= 100

    return sum
```

Comment: Run through the logic by hand for an input of `MCM` - you'll see that it's incorrect.

Comment: Even `IV` doesn't produce the correct result.

Comment: `class Solution` do you have a Java background? Seriously, why the class?

Comment: @timgeb This is how leetcode wants you to do it. I honestly don't know why either...I'm a C++ junkie lol

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I traced it out by hand, and I can't see where it's wrong. I'm definitely overlooking something small. Could you tell me where I messed up?

Comment: Oh I see now! I'm actually adding when I should be subtracting! Ah! Now to change the algorithm. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is not universal acceptance of how the [Roman numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) should be used. E.g. from wikipedia for example both `MCMX` and `MDCCCCX` represent `1910` you should check for every minor number of each digit not just the previous one as you do.

The remarks I could make is:

- You should include both `I` and `V` subtraction in `X` for example. And for the other bigger digits also include all previous smaller numbers. That is for `L` add `X`, `V` and `I` etc.
- If you keep your code as it is you must subtract twice the value since you already have added it once (in the previous step that is). E.g. `IV` will be evaluated as *+1,+5,-1=+5* not +4. You need *+1,+5,**-2**=+5*
- You should check if you are on the first digit i.e. `element=0` then `element-1` has different meaning (last digit that is) and you don't want to check it out.

Maybe your code needs more bug fixing but that's what I found.

Comment: You came just in time. I literally was in the process of fixing my code. I'll take your advice in bug fixing! Thank you!

Comment: A good summary about differences between valid and minimal Roman numbers from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/about=roman_numerals). I found the use of two dictionaries shortened my code. One for the additive, one for the subtractive rules.